# Migrating a web form to web-form with Master

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form up.

Later on, I realized I need a Master Page with a navigation that other web forms should follow.

I am in the process of manually migrating. 
Taking this approach, Create Master Page -> Cut from web form -> Paste to web form with master -> erase the old web form.

As following. (I didn't create a navigation control yet, to not complicate the process further).

[New Master Page]

```
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

[Old Web Form]

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="entityDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=VideoLibraryEntities" DefaultContainerName="VideoLibraryEntities" EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Clips" EntityTypeFilter="Clipo" OnSelecting="EntityDataSource_Selecting">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="entityDataSource">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

        <div>
        <h1>Sending Email</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>From:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>From EMail:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromEmail" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>To:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>To Email:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtToEmail" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subject:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="138px" 
                    Width="467px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send Email" 
                    onclick="btnSend_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" />
</div>
</form>
```

Now shall I create a Master page with navigation and just paste the old web form into the new one?

Thanks.

Comment: What would be a reason to *not* do what you suggest?

Comment: If web forms conflict with names later on, do I have to manually change each one of them? or would a simple cut-paste do that?

Comment: You can't have web forms with the same names, no. Take this moment to setup a *clean solution*. A masterpage, a web form and paste the *body* of your old form into the new one. You don't want the `<% @Register %>` tags to be copied or anything.

Comment: I think this is the right moment to create a right master page, of course including the navigation.